# How do relate or register the digital images to thermal images from FLIR

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, flir

I have a thermal image of 460 X 480 [the thermal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2xzy.jpg), and an digital image of that of 464 X 348 [the digital image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euqq6.jpg). And also an full image of 1280 X 960 [the full digital image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4D6P.jpg). I need to register or relate how the thermal image corresponds to the either of the digital image. (The thermal image seems to be a little zoomed in). I do also have a csv file of the thermal image which is also zoomed in a little but of 464 X 348.
I had tried registering with the thermal and full image which came out real bad.

Just not with this image, different images are different in relation with the original images. some are centre-zoomed in and some are zoomed in on the sides, and some are not at all

Comment: build a calibration target that has detectable features in visible light and thermal. suggestion: screws in a plywood board, charred, with resistive wire wrapped around all of them. visible light image shows black circles on light background. thermal image shows hot circles on cool background. -- cameras must have same optical center or else you can only get a perfect mapping for one **plane in space**, and progressively more error the further away your objects are from that plane.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I believe I do have a thermal camera with a digital camera lens attached to it, a little below the thermal camera lens. so I guess my optical centre is not the same?